# Help getting two select boxes to change the same video 

Tags: javascript, select, youtube-api

I want to be able to have two select boxes, each with different options, to load videos into the same player. I have tried many variations with no luck. (taken from google code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>YouTube Player API Sample</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #videoDiv {
        margin-right: 3px;
      }
      #videoInfo {
        margin-left: 3px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("swfobject", "2.1");
    </script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">


      // Update a particular HTML element with a new value
      function updateHTML(elmId, value) {
        document.getElementById(elmId).innerHTML = value;
      }

      // Loads the selected video into the player.
      function loadVideo() {
        var selectBox = document.getElementById("videoSelection", "videoselection2");
        var videoID = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value

        if(ytplayer) {
          ytplayer.loadVideoById(videoID);
        }
      }

      // This function is called when an error is thrown by the player
      function onPlayerError(errorCode) {
        alert("An error occured of type:" + errorCode);
      }

      // This function is automatically called by the player once it loads
      function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
        ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytPlayer");
        ytplayer.addEventListener("onError", "onPlayerError");
      }

      // The "main method" of this sample. Called when someone clicks "Run".
      function loadPlayer() {
        // The video to load
        var videoID = "ylLzyHk54Z0"
        // Lets Flash from another domain call JavaScript
        var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
        // The element id of the Flash embed
        var atts = { id: "ytPlayer" };
        // All of the magic handled by SWFObject (http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)
        swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID +
                           "&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=player1",
                           "videoDiv", "480", "295", "8", null, null, params, atts);
      }
      function _run() {
        loadPlayer();
      }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(_run);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">

   <div id="videoDiv">Loading...</div>

      <div id="videoControls">
        <p>Select a video to load:</p>
        <select id="videoSelection"  onchange="loadVideo();">
          <option value="ylLzyHk54Z0" selected>YouTube API Overview</option>
          <option value="muLIPWjks_M">Ninja Cat</option>
          <option value="GMUlhuTkM3w">Beatboxing Flute</option>
        </select>

        <select id="videoSelection2"  onchange="loadVideo();">
          <option value="S8V1olWt8I0" selected>AAA</option>
          <option value="FK_hftXn4dk">BBB</option>
          <option value="R94UjwGK8mw">CCC</option>
        </select>
          </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmz, saw a couple of "bugs". Try this:

**HTML**

```
<select id="videoSelection"  onchange="loadVideo(this);">
```

and

```
<select id="videoSelection2"  onchange="loadVideo(this);">
```

**JS**

```
function loadVideo(el) {
    if(!ytplayer)return;
    ytplayer.loadVideoById(el.options[el.selectedIndex].value);
}
```